# I am trying to execute jql query but i am getting error

Tags: java, visualvm, oql

I am trying to execute jql query but i am getting error as follow

i am using visual vm where i dump a file of java application.

query syntax error: identifier should follow class name

```
com.sun.tools.hat.internal.oql.OQLException: query syntax error: identifier should follow class name

    at com.sun.tools.hat.internal.oql.OQLEngine.executeQuery(OQLEngine.java:159)

    at com.sun.tools.hat.internal.server.OQLQuery.executeQuery(OQLQuery.java:85)

    at com.sun.tools.hat.internal.server.OQLQuery.run(OQLQuery.java:77)

    at com.sun.tools.hat.internal.server.HttpReader.run(HttpReader.java:190)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my query is:

```
select * from c;
```

where c is class name. in the class list.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
select x from c x
```

See [OQL documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html) for more details about OQL.